# Fazer uma lista quadriculada HTML

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer uma lista quadriculada, como a da imagem abaixo, apenas com css (favor desconsiderar linhas azuis):[image]

eu achei a função nth-child do css, mas consegui apenas fazer isso:

```
.box_parceiro:nth-child(odd) { background-color: $cinza_noticia_home; }

<ul>
    <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 box_parceiro" ng-repeat="i in vm.repeat(12) track by $index" >
         <h1>ARLETE MARIA SIMON</h1>
         <br>
         <p>
             Peritiba/SC<br>
             (49) 3453-1335<br>
             eraldosimon@hotmail.com
         </p>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Posta  o código que vc já fez

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solução CSS

Sua solução é boa, mas apenas para um número ímpar de colunas:

```
box_parceiro:nth-child(odd)
```

Se o número for ímpar, vai ficar um quadriculado perfeito, pois a última da primeira linha vai necessariamente diferente da primeira da linha seguinte.

Só que com números pares, isto não funciona.

De qualquer forma, tem é uma solução razoavelmente simples para colunas pares. Demonstrei com quatro colunas, mas entendendo a lógica fica fácil.

Se são quatro colunas alternadas, a sequência de cores é essa:

```
A B A B
B A B A
```

repetindo em seguida. Ou seja, temos um ciclo de **8 células** que se repete. Neste ciclo, não precisamos especificar a cor de todas as células, basta colocar uma cor padrão, e mudar outras 4.

Se nosso ciclo é `A B A B B A B A`, temos a cor `B` nas posições 2, 4, 5 e 7. Neste caso, o `nth-child(Nn+I)` pode nos ajudar. Basta trocarmos o `N` pelo tamanho do ciclo, e o `I` pela posição:

```
li:nth-child(8n+2),
li:nth-child(8n+4),
li:nth-child(8n+5),
li:nth-child(8n+7) {
  ... cor ...
}
```

### Solução JavaScript

Caso realmente a quantidade de elementos possa variar quando o usuário redimensionar a janela, uma possível solução seria usar um *script*.

Escrevi um que alterna as classes:

```
function quadriculado( id, cName ) {
    var c = document.getElementById( id );
    var toggle = 0;
    var line = 0;
    var lastY
    for( var i = 0; i < c.children.length; i++ ) {
        var y = c.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var classes = c.children[i].className.replace( cName, '' );
        if( y !== lastY ) { lastY = y; line++; toggle = 0 } else { toggle = 1 - toggle };
        c.children[i].className = classes + ( toggle == line % 2 ? '' : ' ' + cName );
    }
}
```

O único cuidado é você chamar o script no evento de *resize* também:

```
quadriculado( 'elemento', 'classe' );
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){quadriculado( 'elemento', 'classe' )} );
```

Outro ponto a se observar é que, para simplificar, usei uma substituição básica de *string*, então convém usar um nome de classe que não esteja contido em outras classes dos elementos internos.

### Demonstração das duas soluções:

Aqui, uma demonstração da solução CSS, adequada para colunas fixas:

```css
ul {
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  width:25%;
  height:60px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li:nth-child(8n+2),
li:nth-child(8n+4),
li:nth-child(8n+5),
li:nth-child(8n+7) {
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

E aqui, a demonstração da solução JS, adequada para número de colunas variável durante o uso.

Para testar, experimente usar o modo de "página toda" e mudar o tamanho da janela. Se preferir, pode ver diretamente no [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/ZWXbQg).

```js
function quadriculado( id, cName ) {
 var c = document.getElementById( id );
 var toggle = 0;
 var line = 0;
 var lastY
 for( var i = 0; i < c.children.length; i++ ) {
  var y = c.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var classes = c.children[i].className.replace( cName, '' );
  if( y !== lastY ) { lastY = y; line++; toggle = 0 } else { toggle = 1 - toggle };
  c.children[i].className = classes + ( toggle == line % 2 ? '' : ' ' + cName );
 }
}

quadriculado( 'q', 'x-odd' );
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){quadriculado( 'q', 'x-odd' )} );
```

```css
.card {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.x-odd {
  background-color:#ddd;
}

ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="q">
 <li class="card">1</li>
 <li class="card">2</li>
 <li class="card">3</li>
 <li class="card">4</li>
 <li class="card">5</li>
 <li class="card">6</li>
 <li class="card">7</li>
 <li class="card">8</li>
 <li class="card">9</li>
 <li class="card">0</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Olá, sua solução deu certo. O site vai ser responsivo sim e a quantidade de <li> seriam variáveis, pois vai ser cadastrável. Com o seu exemplo vai ficar perfeito. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O importante é o número de colunas, não de `li`. Se o número de colunas for fixo, a melhor solução é a CSS (não importa quantos `li`). Se o número de colunas for variar (pode aparecer 5 em uma tela e 8 em outra, por exemplo), aí tem que ser o JS

Answer (score 0):

```
.box_parceiro { background-color: $cor_padrao; }
.box_parceiro:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color: $cinza_noticia_home; }
```

Comment: Olá, eu fiz o teste e usando da forma que você me passou ele não faz nada de diferente, mas usando apenas (2n) ele apenas substitui os box brancos pela cor cinza, sem criar o efeito quadriculado.

Comment: Poste seu código atual, alguma coisa está atrapalhando o efeito.

Comment: Inseri abaixo do css o código html. A <ul> está apenas com float: left e width: 100% no css e antes da <ul> tem um <div> com loat: left, width: 100% e padding top e bottom apenas.