# Seleção nth-child em uma tabela com colunas pares

Tags: css

Olá quero chegar no seguinte resultado com css:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que com `:nth-child: odd` e `:nth-child: even` seleciona os pares e ímpares, porem na forma que eu quero seria algo assim:

Não, sim, sim, não, não, sim, sim...

Praticamente tirando o primeiro, depois pularia de 2 em 2 os elementos, como consigo com `nth-child` ?

Obs: A imagem é apenas para ilustrar a sequencia da seleção.

Comment: realmente, e ambas duplicatas de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120697/20363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `nth-child()` suporta a definição de padrões cíclicos usando a notação `an+x`, onde `a` é o tamanho do ciclo e `x` é o índice da posição do elemento a selecionar dentro do ciclo.

Na imagem da pergunta você tem ciclos de 4 quadrados, sendo que os quadados 2 e 3 devem ser pretos. Segue exemplo.

```css
/* resposta em si */
.quadrados div:nth-child(4n+2),
.quadrados div:nth-child(4n+3){
 background-color: black;
}

/* montando o "tabuleiro" */
.quadrados {
 display: flex;
 max-width: 220px;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.quadrados div {
 border: 4px solid black;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quadrados">
 <div></div><div></div>
 <div></div><div></div>
 <div></div><div></div>
 <div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

A solução foi obtida [nesta resposta do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23395163/1761121).