# Seletores CSS 3 :nth-child()

Tags: css, css3

Meu código HTML possui 12 tags  que formam 4 blocos de conteúdo por linha, gostaria de aplicar um estilo diferente da seguinte forma com nth-child:

1 div - um estilo CSS
Próximas 3 divs - outro estilo CSS

E assim repetir 1 e 3, 1 e 3, 1 e 3, fiz de um jeito mas responde até a quarta div, na quinta, que seria a 1 da segunda linha, ele já não se aplica.

```
<style>
.tab-content .item-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
}


.tab-content .item-wrap:nth-child(n+1) {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```

E o HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="category-adds" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">

        <div id="category-tab">

            <div class="tab-view">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="grid-view-tab shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                    <li class="small-view-tab active shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                    <li class="list-view-tab shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="category-tab">

                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a style="border-radius: 0px !important;" class="shadow-ads" href="#recent" aria-controls="recent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Destaques</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a style="border-radius: 0px !important;" class="shadow-ads" href="#Random" aria-controls="Random" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Outros destaques</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="tab-content small-view-tab">

                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="recent">                       
                        <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                            <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                <div class="item-image">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                    <div class="item-price">
                                        <span>R$3950</span>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-description">
                                    <div class="item-title">
                                        <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item-info">
                                        <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2">
                            <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                            <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                <div class="item-image">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                        <div class="item-price">
                                            <span>R$3950</span>
                                        </div> 
                                </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                    <div class="item-price">
                                        <span>R$19</span>
                                    </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Disital Multi Headphone</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                <div class="item-price">
                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-description">
                                <div class="item-title">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info">
                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

O motivo de utilizar o :nth-child é que nos blocos da primeira coluna a div deve estar colada na DIV pai, e as demais com padding pada separar uma da outra, pois uso o BOOTSTRAP 3 para trabalhar com a estrutura HTMLe CSS, então dividi o container com 4 colunas por linha (col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4).

Na amostra abaixo segue parte da disposição dos blocos de conteúdo, e como gostaria que ficassem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível coloque tb o HTML

Comment: @hugocsl Feito!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%c3%bameros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last)

Comment: Somada com essa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121024/70

Comment: @Bacco Acabei de usar sua resposta como referência :D

Comment: @Bacco não creio ser duplicata, pois a necessidade é salto de 1 e 3, 1 e 3, li estas publicações porém não funcionou para o meu problema.

Comment: @EliseuB. o segundo link mostra como resolver a questão das linhas. Entendendo o primeiro, que é o funcionamento, já responde a pergunta (que, por sinal, é o mesmo conhecimento aplicado na resposta do colega Hugo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc precisa fazer uma regra no `nth-child` para pegar de 4 em 4.

```
nth-child(4n + 1)
```

Vc pode ler mais sobre isso nessa excelente resposta: [O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%C3%BAmeros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last/148591#148591)

Já o `padding` como vai ser igual em todos os filho basta vc colocar direto na classe: `.tab-content .item-wrap { padding... }`

Segue o exemplo trocando a cor do texto e mantendo o padding que vc precisa.

```css
    .tab-content .item-wrap {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
}


.tab-content .item-wrap:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



        <div class="container">

                <div class="category-adds" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; z-index: 1;">
            
                    <div id="category-tab">
            
                        <div class="tab-view">
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li class="grid-view-tab shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                <li class="small-view-tab active shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                <li class="list-view-tab shadow-ads"><i class="fa fa-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
            
                        <div class="category-tab">
            
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a style="border-radius: 0px !important;" class="shadow-ads" href="#recent" aria-controls="recent" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Destaques</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a style="border-radius: 0px !important;" class="shadow-ads" href="#Random" aria-controls="Random" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Outros destaques</a></li>
                            </ul>
            
                            <div class="tab-content small-view-tab">
            
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="recent">                       
                                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                            <div class="item-image">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                                <div class="item-price">
                                                    <span>R$3950</span>
                                                </div> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-description">
                                                <div class="item-title">
                                                    <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="item-info">
                                                    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
            
                                    <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2">
                                        <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                        <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                            <div class="item-image">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                                    <div class="item-price">
                                                        <span>R$3950</span>
                                                    </div> 
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                                <div class="item-price">
                                                    <span>R$19</span>
                                                </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Disital Multi Headphone</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                            <div class="item-price">
                                                <span>R$3950</span>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                            <div class="item-price">
                                                <span>R$3950</span>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                            <div class="item-price">
                                                <span>R$3950</span>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                            <div class="item-price">
                                                <span>R$3950</span>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                                <div class="item-wrap image-wrap-corner-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <img class="corner" src="assets/images/premium-corner.png">
                                    <div class="item shadow-ads">
                                        <div class="item-image">
                                            <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"></a>
                                            <div class="item-price">
                                                <span>R$3950</span>
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-description">
                                            <div class="item-title">
                                                <h3><a href="#">Diecast Model Motorcycle</a></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item-info">
                                                <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            
                            </div>
            
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: Não resolveu, pois os blocos grudaram todos, sem espaçamento.

Comment: @EliseuB. ai é uma questão de padding, repare que eu já editei a resposta e fiz o ajuste, Executa ai de novo pra ver como ficou

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, perfieto! Gratidão.

Comment: @EliseuB. cara não deixe de ler os links citados para entende direitinho como construir a regra, vai te ajudar em outras ocasiões! Tmj

Comment: Tá bem, vou ler mais sobre os seletores, comecei aqui mas tá entrando aos poucos na cabeça, a regra entendi, mas a estitização me perdi,  porisso fiz desse modo errôneo, mas vou me esforçar mais para isso e um dia ajudar os outros aqui.