# Preciso quebrar a linha

Tags: php, html

Ola estou com problema que não me deixa em paz, preciso que quando essas células da tabela cheguem em 4 em cada linha ela pular para a próxima, mas está ai o problema estou puxando essas células do banco de dados usando o $dado["descricao_map"]; não sei o que fazer.

```
<?php 
include("ArquivoConexão.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM materialapoio";
$con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../IMAGENS/Favicon.png" />
    <link rel="icon" href="../IMAGENS/Favicon.png" type="../image/x-icon" />
    <meta content="IE=edge"http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kep</title>
    <link href=../CSS/Estilo_02.css rel=stylesheet>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/JS_02.js"></script>
</head>
<body class=Modelo01>
    <div class=PaginaCompleta>
        <div id=MenuTotal class="Div_Menu_Oculto PositionAb" style="width: 5%">
            <input type="checkbox" id="navicon" onclick="Aumentar('MenuTotal') & Diminuir('Conteudo') & Aparecer('Menu') & Aparecer('Logo')"/>
            <div class="nav-toggle">
                <label for="navicon" class="menu">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <img id=Logo class="PositionRe LogoCompleto"src=../IMAGENS/LogoTCC.png style="display: none">
            <div id=Menu class="PositionAb BotoesMenu" style="display: none">
                <input type=button class="BotaoMenu PositionRe FonteArial" value="MATERIAL DE APOIO" onclick="MaterialDeApoio()">
                <input type=button class="BotaoMenu BotaoMenu2 PositionRe FonteArial" value="CALENDÁRIO" onclick="Home()">
                <input type=button class="BotaoMenu BotaoMenu3 PositionRe FonteArial" value="LISTA DE TAREFAS" onclick="ListaDeTarefa()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Div_Conteudo  Con_Maior PositionAb" id=Conteudo style="width: 95%">
            <div class="Div_Cabeçalho PositionRe">
                <div class="PositionRe BotoesCabeçalho BT_Menor">
                    <input type=button class="PositionRe IconesCabeçalho iconeHome" onclick="Home()">
                    <input type=button class="PositionRe IconesCabeçalho Home" onclick="Sair()">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="BlocoDasListas PositionRe">
                <div class="FonteArial TituloTarefas PositionRe">Material de apoio</div>
                <div class=BlocoMaterial>
                    <table class="FonteArial FormataçãoMateriais">
                        <tr class="LinhaMaterial1">
                            <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
                                <td class="Colunas01"><?php echo $dado["descricao_map"];?></td>
                            <?php }?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: aqui esta um exemplo do que eu estou tentando fazer]

Comment: Olha se isso resolve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/324963/como-colocar-um-limite-de-4-imagens-por-linha/324976#324976 Vc precisa estruturar o seu HTML para quebrar dessa forma, depois vc popula com o que vier do banco e ai vai quebrar corretamente de acordo como o CSS feito para receber o conteúdo

Comment: Desculpa falar uma coisa meio nada a ver, mas... porque não usa Bootstrap? Lá você já tem o grid pronto. É sempre 12. Daí você pode colocar `col-md-3`, que vão caber 4.

Comment: É uma boa pratica marcar uma resposta que lhe atendeu como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,
Utilizando o padrão de percentual e não o de pixel, pois dessa forma isso vai se adequar independente do navegador.
Tenta algo desse tipo:

```html
<div id="pai" style="widht:100%">
   <div id="filho" style="widht:25%"></div>
   <div id="filho" style="widht:25%"></div>
   <div id="filho" style="widht:25%"></div>
   <div id="filho" style="widht:25%"></div>
   <div id="filho" style="widht:25%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitando o seu código, daria resultado dessa forma.

```
<table class="FonteArial FormataçãoMateriais">

    <?php 
        $numerocolunas = 4; 

        while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ 

        echo "<tr class='LinhaMaterial1'>";
            for ($x = 0; $x < $numerocolunas; $x++) {
                echo "<td class='Colunas01'>".$dado["descricao_map"]."</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>";

        }
  ?>

</table>
```

> É só um detalhe, mostrar como poderia ter sido feito levando em conta o código da pergunta e a pergunta em si é: `preciso que quando essas células da tabela cheguem em 4 em cada linha ela pular para a próxima`. Nesse caso a minha resposta aponta como isso pode ser feito, agora se a pergunta fosse outra `existe uma forma melhor de fazer isso` certamente a resposta seria outra. Isso só pra deixar aqui a minha indignação aos downsvote.

Essa situação se parece com alguém perguntando ao seu mecânico: `qual a solução para o defeito do meu fusquinha`, a resposta, então seria, `olha compra um Mercedes zero quilometro que é melhor`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar flexbox! Torna o layout responsivo e de fácil manutenção.

Por exemplo, você define um escopo inicial, com algumas `div`'s. E a partir delas podemos definir um tamanho fixo utilizando `px` ou com porcentagem.

O exemplo abaixo foi feito com tamanho fixo, utilizando `px`'s.

A partir disso demos um `display: flex` para a `div` pai, e adicionamos a propriedade `flex-wrap: wrap` que permitirá a `div` "ir para baixo sozinha", pois, por padrão, todos os itens vão tentar ficar em uma linha só.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
 
  display: flex;
  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

Para mais informações sobre flexbox confira esse [guia](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).